# Generating json file in database instead of java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, plsql

I am reading one `table` from database using `resultset`. later I am using this data to generate json file.

I want to generate `json` file in database and return that file to `java` because my java code is going to consume `POST API.`

code is something like this

```
    String query="select * from dynamicentitygtt";
    PreparedStatement prepstatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs=prepstatement.executeQuery()
        while rs.next()
        {
          //Load data to POJO
            
        }
      //call method to generate json file.
      //Inject file data to API
```

what I want.

```
String query="select * from dynamicentitygtt";
        PreparedStatement prepstatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs=prepstatement.executeQuery()
        //here I want file from database.
```

My database should return json file. i can create procedure in database. i can also use callable. I can also create json file from table.
But i dont know how to return file from database.

forgive me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: You could create a pl/sql procedure that performs the query and returns a clob containing the desired json (and call the procedure from Java). There are at least a couple of options for doing it, depending on your Oracle version and your preference. I personally use https://github.com/pljson/pljson but if you have Oracle 18 or later you probably can do it with the native JSON methods.

Comment: "I don't know how to return file from database" Perfect - that identifies the real problem you need help with. Read about the `UTL_FILE` package, or - more generally - use any method you are comfortable with to read about file operations from within Oracle database. This has nothing to do with the content of the files (JSON or whatever else).

Comment: @mathguy thank you so much mathguy. I am going through the same.

Comment: You should include the version of Oracle in such questions. Later versions of the database have enhanced capabilities.

Comment: I am using  oracle 18c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have noted that you are on Oracle 18c, you have access to the [JSON_OBJECT, JSON_OBJECTAGG, JSON_ARRAY, and JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A) SQL functions.  Using these functions, you should be able to create the JSON structure you need just with a SQL query instead of needing to generate a file and pass it back to your Java call. One item to note is that if you are generating large JSON objects, you will want to modify the **RETURNING** clause in any of the JSON function calls in the query or your JSON will not be valid.

Below are some examples on how to use the functions:

#### Query #1

```
WITH
    emp (employee_id,
         first_name,
         last_name,
         department_number)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'John', 'Doe', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Jane', 'Smith', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Robert', 'Jones', 200 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Alan', 'Carter', 300 FROM DUAL)
SELECT json_arrayagg (json_object (*))
  FROM emp;
```

#### Result #1 (beautified)

```
[
  {
    "EMPLOYEE_ID": 1,
    "FIRST_NAME": "John",
    "LAST_NAME": "Doe",
    "DEPARTMENT_NUMBER": 100
  },
  {
    "EMPLOYEE_ID": 2,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Jane",
    "LAST_NAME": "Smith",
    "DEPARTMENT_NUMBER": 100
  },
  {
    "EMPLOYEE_ID": 3,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Robert",
    "LAST_NAME": "Jones",
    "DEPARTMENT_NUMBER": 200
  },
  {
    "EMPLOYEE_ID": 4,
    "FIRST_NAME": "Alan",
    "LAST_NAME": "Carter",
    "DEPARTMENT_NUMBER": 300
  }
]
```

#### Query #2

```
WITH
    emp (employee_id,
         first_name,
         last_name,
         department_number)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'John', 'Doe', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Jane', 'Smith', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Robert', 'Jones', 200 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Alan', 'Carter', 300 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT json_arrayagg (
             json_object (
                     'department_number' VALUE department_number,
                     'employees' VALUE
                         json_arrayagg (
                             json_object ('first_name' VALUE first_name, 'last_name' VALUE last_name))))
    FROM emp
GROUP BY department_number;
```

#### Result #2 (beautified)

```
[
  {
    "department_number": 100,
    "employees": [
      { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe" },
      { "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Smith" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "department_number": 200,
    "employees": [{ "first_name": "Robert", "last_name": "Jones" }]
  },
  {
    "department_number": 300,
    "employees": [{ "first_name": "Alan", "last_name": "Carter" }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

In java using below method you can create List of Map<String,String>.

Where Map have key of columnName and value as value of that column.

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnNumber = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            int count = 1;
            while (count <= columnNumber) {
                String columnName = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(count);
                map.put(columnName, resultSet.getString(columnName));
                count++;
            }
            mapList.add(map);
        }
        return mapList;
    }
```

Once you are able to create Map, you can create any json string or json object from it using multiple library [**`like this`**](https://devqa.io/how-to-convert-java-map-to-json/)

This will help you.

Comment: OP wants to generate the json in db not in Java. So war you suggest ancode to do ist in Java?